# Biodegradation time for biodegradable shopping bags?

Tags: environmental-protection

How long does it take for the plastic/polythene shopping bags marked **biodegradable** to *biodegrade*?

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange! I found [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biodegradable_plastic), [two](http://www.motherjones.com/environment/2009/05/do-biodegradable-plastics-really-work), [three](http://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/everyday-myths/how-long-does-it-take-for-plastics-to-biodegrade.htm) leads quite easily... Maybe you will have more specific questions after some research.

Comment: Thanks @kwinkunks. But I have read these and other articles on the web and none gives  a definitive answer (or any at all)! My own conclusion is that in nature biodegradable plastics/shopping-bags don't biodegrade at all! They only biodegrade in controlled, usually industrial, conditions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it more suitable for http://sustainability.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BHF I'm inclined to agree, but I can imagine more specific versions of this question that are about physical processes in/on the earth. If the OP cares to ask such a question...

Comment: You will have to define *biodegradable* if you want answers based on facts, i.e. you can only expect a meaningful answer (also on http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) if you ask for a bag **made of .....**